# MATLab - Database Handle is Empty

Tags: database, oracle, matlab

I have the following problem. At work we have personal computers running windows7 with MATLab (including the database toolbox), Oracle and so on. I got a new process I should take care about which involves a MATLab script which connects to the oracle database. The scripts works fine on any computer of the department except of mine. Sadly the IT told me that every PC is configured the same and I have to find the misstake for my one.

So i started "debugging" by checking the connection struct MATLab creates when it connects via

```
conn = database(instance,username,password)
```

It appears that the content of the structure is equal to every one else, except that the handle is empty:

```
val =
   Instance: '***'
   UserName: '*'
     Driver: []
        URL: []
Constructor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.databaseConnect]
    Message: [1x128 char]
     Handle: 0
    TimeOut: 0
 AutoCommit: 'off'
       Type: 'Database Object'
```

on all other systems the handle is set to:

sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection

So my question is: Do I have to configure MATLab or is the driver for the JDBC/ODBC is missing? I already checked systems preferences/adminstration/ODBC sources but it seems to by the same as everywhere else.

Do someone might know how I can track down the source of this issue? Any help or hint is highly apprechiated.

Thanks and best regards
stephan

Comment: I have run in what I think is a similar problem and I had to update/download Sun software.

Answer (score 0):

after some research here is the way one can figure it out. It is actually very easy, but I did not try the obvious...

first, if the

```
   connection = database(...)
```

can not be created, type

```
connection.message
```

in the MATLab console. This message will give you additional feedback on the error. In my case the DNS entries for the oracle Databases where empty. After adding them through system preferences it worked as expected.